# Converting XmlDocument to Dictionary<string, string>

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm looking for a good way to convert an `XmlDocument` to `Dictionary<string, string>` using Linq.

My xml is formatted like this:

```
<config>
    <field>value</field>
    <field2>value2</field2>
</config>
```

I'd like to put this into a Dictionary with key value pairs looking like this:

field, value
field2, value2

I'm thinking I should use Linq to do this but I'm not sure about the syntax.

Comment: Is there single <config/> node in XML document or string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont know if its the better way, but its clean & simple..

```
XElement xdoc = XElement.Load("yourFilePath");
Dictionary<string, string> result = (from element in xdoc.Elements() select new KeyValuePair<string, string>(element.Name.ToString(), element.Value)).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Comment: Well, linq its like a must-know tech nowadays... the idea was to deliver a very short solution, but you can go with the foreach statement to...

Answer (score 6):

Using an `XmlDocument`, per your question, you can use this approach to get a `Dictionary<string, string>`.

```
string input = @"<config>
    <field>value</field>
    <field2>value2</field2>
</config>";

var xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(input);

var dict = xml.SelectNodes("/config/*")
              .Cast<XmlNode>()
              .ToDictionary(n => n.Name, n => n.InnerText);
```

If you can use an `XElement`, you can use either the `Parse` method to load the XML from a string, or use the `Load` method to load it from a file. Then this approach should suffice:

```
var xml = XElement.Parse(input);
var dict = xml.Elements()
              .ToDictionary(n => n.Name.LocalName, n => n.Value);
```

Comment: +1 because I like your method quite a bit more than mine. Your method is much more direct than mine and now I'm aware of the ToDictionary call.

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing it with linq would be the following
Create an XML document using

```
XElement xDoc = XElement.Parse("<config><field>value</field><field2>value2</field2</config>");
```

For simplicity, I inlined your XML snippet into the parse directly.

Then you can create a query with the following

```
var query = from xEle in xDoc.Descendants()
select new { tag = xEle.Name.LocalName, value = xEle.Value };
```

Then convert that query to a dictionary using a simple for each loop.

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (var CurNode in query)
{
    dictionary.Add(CurNode.tag, CurNode.value);
}
```

Comment: +1 for the effort. A more direct approach is to use the `ToDictionary` method. See my response for an example.