# XML Read Attribute issue

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net

Following is my xml snippet:

```xml
<root>
  <EmployeeSearcher_CMSRequest xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/xxxx" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <IsActive>A</IsActive>
    <DepartmentCode>4775</DepartmentCode>
    <OfficeCode>KA016</OfficeCode>
    <EmployeeFirstName>James</EmployeeFirstName>
    <EmployeeId>0043044</EmployeeId>
    <EmployeeLastName>Malarkey</EmployeeLastName>
  </EmployeeSearcher_CMSRequest>
</root>
```

Following is the code to retrieve xml data:

```vb
Public Function GetRequest(Of TRequest)(Optional ByVal fileName As String = Nothing) As TRequest()
    Dim objCertificateCountRequest As List(Of TRequest) = New List(Of TRequest)
    Dim serializer As DataContractSerializer = New DataContractSerializer(GetType(TRequest))

    'Get the assembly folder
    Dim assemblyPath As String = New Uri(Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath
    'Get the file name
    If (IsNothing(fileName)) Then
        fileName = Path.GetDirectoryName(assemblyPath) + testDataForlder + GetType(TRequest).Name + ".xml"
    Else
        fileName = Path.GetDirectoryName(assemblyPath) + testDataForlder + fileName + ".xml"
    End If

    Try
        Dim settings As New XmlReaderSettings()
        settings.IgnoreWhitespace = True
        Dim reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(fileName, settings)

        reader.ReadStartElement("root")

        While reader.IsStartElement(GetType(TRequest).Name)

            objCertificateCountRequest.Add(CType(serializer.ReadObject(reader), TRequest))

        End While

        reader.ReadEndElement() 'Read root
        reader.Close()

        Return objCertificateCountRequest.ToArray()
    Catch ex As Exception

        Throw New System.Exception("Error deserializing input xml for Request:" + GetType(TRequest).Name + vbLf + ex.Message)

    End Try

End Function
```

While retrieving data from xml only 1st attribute and `<OfficeCode>` is read. Besides that no values are getting read. Please suggest something.

Comment: Perhaps consider [deserializing the XML](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/292726/Serialization-Part-III-XML-Serialization)? It would give you a better structure of your data in-code.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you use `XmlReader`? Linq to Xml could be an intuitive alternative.

Comment: Since you are using VB, [consider using LINQ to XML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10805100/87698), which has native language support.

Comment: @VisualVincent Yes will try that

Comment: @AlexB.This is an existing code and for all the previous methods it has been there so cannot really change the code as it is working appropriately for all other methods.

Answer (score 0):

You need a namespace.  Try xml linq

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Module Module1
    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Sub Main()
        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(FILENAME)
        Dim request = doc.Descendants().Where(Function(x) x.Name.LocalName = "EmployeeSearcher_CMSRequest")
        Dim ns As XNamespace = request.FirstOrDefault().GetDefaultNamespace
        Dim employee = request.Select(Function(x) New With { _
            .isActive = x.Element(ns + "IsActive").Value,
            .departmentCode = x.Element(ns + "DepartmentCode").Value,
            .officeCode = x.Element(ns + "OfficeCode").Value,
            .employeeFirstName = x.Element(ns + "EmployeeFirstName").Value,
            .employeeId = x.Element(ns + "EmployeeId").Value,
            .employeeLastName = x.Element(ns + "EmployeeLastName").Value
         }).FirstOrDefault()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: If you add `Imports <xmlns:xxxx="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/xxxx">` at the top, you could even use VB's native LINQ-to-XML syntax, e.g. `.isActive = x.<xxxx:IsActive>.Value`.

Comment: There are many methods and I cannot write that function for one particular one . It has to be dynamic and it is doing so for all other 32 odd methods.

Comment: You just can't read data randomly and then expect to process the results.  You must have some sort of organization.  Dynamic reading of data just isn't very useful.