# How to convert an xml file to dictionary in vb using paste special

Tags: xml, vb.net, dictionary

I have an XML file look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <Description>
    <name>Beth</name>
    <kod>21</kod>
    <role>Manager</role>
    <age>34</age>
  </Description>

  <Description>
    <name>James</name>
    <kod>3</kod>
    <role>Human Resources</role>
    <age>28</age>
  </Description>

  <Description>
    <name>Vickie</name>
    <kod>5</kod>
    <role>Human Resources</role>
    <age>30</age>
  </Description>
</root>
```

I want to read this XML, and turn it into a dictionary, where the key will be the kod, and the value will be all other params (name, role, age).
Today I have something else and I have a trouble to change it.

Today I have this:

I started by creating an automatic class from visual studio.
(copy the xml and then in visual --> Edit--> Paste Special --> Paste XML as classes.
This create a class look like this:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports System.IO

<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=True),
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute([Namespace]:="", IsNullable:=False)>
Partial Public Class root

    Private descriptionField() As rootDescription

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Description")>
    Public Property Description() As rootDescription()
        Get
            Return Me.descriptionField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.descriptionField = Value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

'''<remarks/>
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=True)>
Partial Public Class rootDescription

    Private nameField As String

    Private kodField As Integer

    Private roleField As String

    Private ageField As Integer

    '''<remarks/>
    Public Property name() As String
        Get
            Return Me.nameField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.nameField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    Public Property kod() As Integer
        Get
            Return Me.kodField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.kodField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    Public Property role() As String
        Get
            Return Me.roleField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.roleField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    Public Property age() As Integer
        Get
            Return Me.ageField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.ageField = Value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Then I create XMLHelper class to read the XML:

```
Public Class XMLHelper

    Public Shared Function ReadXml(Of ObjectType)(ByVal fileName As String) As ObjectType
        Using sw = New StreamReader(fileName)
            Return CType(New XmlSerializer(GetType(ObjectType)).Deserialize(sw), ObjectType)
        End Using
    End Function
End Class
```

And in other class I do the following command:

```
 Dim xmlData = XMLHelper.ReadXml(Of root)(xmlFilePath)
```

This fill my xmlData.

Now I need to turn the xml into dictionary ,take the key from one of the xml fields, and to do it with minimum changes as possible from the current code.

I saw a similar  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804917/convert-xml-to-vb-net-dictionary) elsewhere but it did not help me and does not work in my code

hope you can help me.

Answer (score 2):

Using Xml Linq :

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Module Module1
    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Sub Main()
        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(FILENAME)

        Dim dict As Dictionary(Of Integer, Description) = doc.Descendants("Description") _
           .GroupBy(Function(x) CType(x.Element("kod"), Integer), Function(y) New Description() With { _
                                                           .name = CType(y.Element("name"), String), _
                                                           .kod = CType(y.Element("kod"), Integer), _
                                                           .role = CType(y.Element("role"), String), _
                                                           .age = CType(y.Element("age"), Integer) _
                                                       }) _
          .ToDictionary(Function(x) x.Key, Function(y) y.FirstOrDefault())
    End Sub

End Module
Public Class Description
    Public name As String
    Public kod As Integer
    Public role As String
    Public age As Integer
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Using your code an approach might be using `XmlDocument` to read your Xml then populate a `Dictionary` of your rootDescription/Xml mirror class. To do that just add the function below `ReadXmlAsDictionary` to your `XMLHelper` class.I have used `For - Loop` as I think is more easy for you understanding the concept.

```
Public Class XMLHelper

    Public Shared Function ReadXml(Of ObjectType)(ByVal fileName As String) As ObjectType
        Using sw = New StreamReader(fileName)
            Return CType(New XmlSerializer(GetType(ObjectType)).Deserialize(sw), ObjectType)
        End Using
    End Function

    Public Shared Function ReadXmlAsDictionary(ByVal fileName As String) As Dictionary(Of Integer, rootDescription)

        Dim result As Dictionary(Of Integer, rootDescription) = New Dictionary(Of Integer, rootDescription)
        Using sw As StreamReader = New StreamReader(fileName)
            Dim xmlDoc As Xml.XmlDocument = New Xml.XmlDocument
            Try
                xmlDoc.Load(sw)
                Dim allElements = From element As Xml.XmlElement In xmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes
                                  Select name = Trim(element.GetElementsByTagName("name")(0).InnerText),
                                      kod = Trim(element.GetElementsByTagName("kod")(0).InnerText),
                                      role = Trim(element.GetElementsByTagName("role")(0).InnerText),
                                      age = Trim(element.GetElementsByTagName("age")(0).InnerText)


                For Each current In allElements
                    If Not result.ContainsKey(CInt(current.kod)) Then
                        result.Add(current.kod, New rootDescription With {
                                   .kod = current.kod,
                                   .name = current.name,
                                   .role = current.role,
                                   .age = current.age})
                    End If
                Next

            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.ToString)
            End Try

        End Using

        Return result

    End Function



End Class
```

Usage:

```
Dim dictData As Dictionary(Of Integer, rootDescription) = XMLHelper.ReadXmlAsDictionary("C:\Users\YourUser\Desktop\test.xml")

Console.WriteLine($" Name: {dictData.Item(21).name}  Age: {dictData.Item(21).age}  Role: {dictData.Item(21).role }  Kod: {dictData.Item(21).kod} ")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using xelement

```
Private dict As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Descr)

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim path As String = "your path here"
    Dim xe As XElement
    ' xe = XElement.Load(path) 'production

    ' for TESTING use literal.  Get rid of this for production
    xe = <root>
             <Description>
                 <name>Beth</name>
                 <kod>21</kod>
                 <role>Manager</role>
                 <age>34</age>
             </Description>

             <Description>
                 <name>James</name>
                 <kod>3</kod>
                 <role>Human Resources</role>
                 <age>28</age>
             </Description>

             <Description>
                 <name>Vickie</name>
                 <kod>5</kod>
                 <role>Human Resources</role>
                 <age>30</age>
             </Description>
         </root>

    'create the dictionary
    For Each el As XElement In xe.Elements
        Me.dict.Add(Integer.Parse(el.<kod>.Value), New Descr(el))
    Next

    'see if it worked
    For Each d As Descr In dict.Values
        Debug.WriteLine("---")
        Debug.WriteLine(d.nameField)
        Debug.WriteLine(d.kodField)
        Debug.WriteLine(d.roleField)
        Debug.WriteLine(d.ageField)
    Next
End Sub

Public Class Descr
    ' _el e.g. after constructor
    '    <Description>
    '      <name>Beth</name>
    '      <kod>21</kod>
    '      <role>Manager</role>
    '      <age>34</age>
    '    </Description>
    Private _el As XElement
    Public Sub New(el As XElement)
        Me._el = el 'reference
    End Sub

    Public Function nameField() As String
        Return Me._el.<name>.Value
    End Function

    Public Function kodField() As Integer
        Return Integer.Parse(Me._el.<kod>.Value)
    End Function

    Public Function roleField() As String
        Return Me._el.<role>.Value
    End Function

    Public Function ageField() As Integer
        Return Integer.Parse(Me._el.<age>.Value)
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly simplified (you don't need backing fields here) and change the Root class name to **`DescriptionRoot`** to avoid using a non-descriptive class name (so you don't have all of your root classes named `root` :).

- The root element in the XML remains `root`, as defined in the XmlAttributes applied to the class objects.
- Changed the Type of the Root element property to `List(Of Description)`.

After the deserialization, you just need to call [ToDictionary()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary) on the `List(Of Description)` objects defined by the root element.
Take the `kod` value as the Key and the class object, `Description`, as the Value:

```
Imports System.Xml.Serialization

<Serializable>
<XmlType(AnonymousType:=False), XmlRoot("root", [Namespace]:="", IsNullable:=False)>
Partial Public Class DescriptionRoot
    <XmlElement("Description")>
    Public Property Descriptions As List(Of Description)
End Class

<Serializable>
<XmlRoot("root", [Namespace]:="")>
Partial Public Class Description
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property kod As Integer
    Public Property role As String
    Public Property age As Integer
End Class
```

---

Declare your `Dictionary(Of Integer, Description)`, deserialize and call `ToDictionary()` on the `List(Of Description)` object:

- There isn't a way to convert to Dictionary a generic object (as it appears you're trying to) using the value of one of the properties, unless these objects implement a specific/known Interface.
  Otherwise you could use a progressive index as the Key of the Dictionary.

```
Dim dicOfDescriptions = New Dictionary(Of Integer, Description)
Using sr As New StreamReader("[File Path]")
    Dim root = DirectCast(New XmlSerializer(GetType(DescriptionRoot)).Deserialize(sr), DescriptionRoot)
    dicOfDescriptions = root.Descriptions.ToDictionary(Function(desc) desc.kod, Function(desc) desc)
End Using
```

To create the Dictionary using a progressive value as the Key:

```
dicOfDescriptions = root.Descriptions.Select(Function(o, i) New With {.Index = i, .Value = o}).
    ToDictionary(Function(a) a.Index, Function(a) a.Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding `[...] and to do it with minimum changes as possible from the current code.`

I came up with three simple solutions:

```vb
      'Use rootDescription as value object 
       Dim lookup = xmlData.Description.ToLookup(Of Integer, rootDescription)(Function(x) x.kod, Function(x) x)
       Dim dict = lookup.ToDictionary(Function(x) x.Key, Function(x) x.ToList())

      'OR Use an anonymous type as value object if you don´t need it in other functions 
       Dim lookup2 = xmlData.Description.ToLookup(Function(x) x.kod, Function(x) New With {Key .name = x.name, Key .age = x.age, Key .role = x.role})
       Dim dict2 = lookup2.ToDictionary(Function(x) x.Key, Function(x) x.ToList())

      'OR use an own class, e.g. Description
       Dim lookup3 = xmlData.Description.ToLookup(Function(x) x.kod, Function(x) New Description() With {.Name = x.name, .Age = x.age, .Role = x.role})
       Dim dict3 = lookup3.ToDictionary(Function(x) x.Key, Function(x) x.ToList())
```